# How to concatenate columns of a dataframe vertically using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple column and now suppose I want to pick few of the columns and concatenate them vertically and create a new column altogether.

For instance below is a df having 3 columns(consider commas are used to separate column values)

```
 Column1                                        Column2                             Column3
 American Depositary Receipts Level I (ADRs)    Core Banking Transaction Account   Credit Obligation
```

I want to append column2 below column1 and create a new column as column4

```
Column4
American Depositary Receipts Level I (ADRs)
```

Credit Obligation

Core Banking
Credit

Comment: It's not clear from the formatting what the structure of the dataframe is at first. How many rows are being presented? Also how many rows in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new series out of your appended columns. Then you can join it back or do whatever you want with it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = df['b'].append(df['a']).reset_index(drop=True)
```